# How can I tell if more than one 'IFS' condition is 'TRUE' and not just the first match?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel 365 I'm using an "IFS" statement to scan through a number of columns to find out if a cell's value is in any of the columns. I believe "IFS" will process all your conditions until it reaches the first one that is "TRUE" then output. However, I'd like to be able to find ALL instances where my condition is true and output or evaluate them all somehow. Is there a way to do this with IFS (or some other method)? I think I'd like to output the matching value for each true condition in a separate row, but anything that could help me see how many matched and/or which column each match is in would be helpful.

The code I have is a bit much to share as my columns are in other workbooks, so I'll just share a close example. This formula would be in a  cell that outputs the match, column D below.

```
  A  |  B   |  C   |    D    |  E
------------------------------------
ColA | Col1 | Col2 | Formula | Notes
------------------------------------
  1  |   1  |   2  |    1    | Two matches in same column (Col1)
  2  |   1  |   2  |    2    | Two matches in same column (Col2)
  3  |   3  |   3  |    3    | Two matches in diff column (Col1 & Col2)

=IFS(
NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT("A"&(ROW())),INDIRECT("B:B"),0))),
INDEX(INDIRECT("B:B"),MATCH(INDIRECT("A"&(ROW())),INDIRECT("B:B"),0)),
NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT("A"&(ROW())),INDIRECT("C:C"),0))),
INDEX(INDIRECT("C:C"),MATCH(INDIRECT("A"&(ROW())),INDIRECT("C:C"),0))
)
```

Of course the expected output is to dump the matching value of the first condition that's true, but I'd like to output all instances the condition is true in separate rows if possible. Maybe something like this...

```
  A  |  B   |  C   |    D    |  E
------------------------------------
ColA | Col1 | Col2 | Formula | Notes
------------------------------------
  1  |   1  |   2  |    1    | Two matches in same column (Col1)
 ... |  ... |  ... |    1    | Two matches in same column (Col1)
  2  |   1  |   2  |    2    | Two matches in same column (Col2)
 ... |  ... |  ... |    2    | Two matches in same column (Col2)
  3  |   3  |   3  |    3    | Two matches in diff column (Col1 & Col2)
 ... |  ... |  ... |    3    | Two matches in diff column (Col1 & Col2)
```

In the above and in my actual case the '...' would display what's in the column of that particular row match, which may vary from one row to another row throughout the worksheets. Basically, column D in the example would be on a separate 'results' sheet with the same amount of columns and column value types as all the 'data' sheets being searched. Furthermore, each column of the 'results' sheet would be a formula scanning that one specific column in all sheets, but only outputting the given column value of the matched row. Something like below...

```
     DATA SHEET
  A   |   B   |   C   
----------------------
FName | LName | Amount 
----------------------
John  | Doe   |  10    
Jane  | Doe   |  4    
Jack  | Black |  10    

    RESULTS SHEET 
(all cells are formulas)
  A   |   B   |   C   
----------------------
FName | LName | Amount 
----------------------
John  | Doe   |  10   < matching value in C     
Jack  | Black |  10   < but different A & C
```

I hope that last part answered any "why" questions. ;)

**ADDITION (7/25/19):** 
Below is the complete formula I'm using on sheets like above, but with more columns. It works well with the exception of **my requirement to know where ALL matches occur and not just the first match on the IFS statement**. Column "F" is the column I'm matching to output the corresponding value from the column cell on the match's row as found on the data sheets (5 sheets) to the formulated 'results' sheet, as displayed above. The only thing that changes in the formula between cells is the "A:A" to "B:B" etc., including "F:F" (the column with the value to be "MATCHED" from "SOURCES!$B$2"), which I made the last condition in the formula case nothing is found in the other data sheets, pasting its own data in lieu of something like 0, N/A, or FALSE.

```
=IFS(
NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F"&(ROW())),INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$3)&"F:F"),0))),
INDEX(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$3)&"A:A"),MATCH(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F"&(ROW())),INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$3)&"F:F"),0)),
NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F"&(ROW())),INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$4)&"F:F"),0))),
INDEX(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$4)&"A:A"),MATCH(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F"&(ROW())),INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$4)&"F:F"),0)),
NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F"&(ROW())),INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$12)&"F:F"),0))),
INDEX(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$12)&"A:A"),MATCH(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F"&(ROW())),INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$12)&"F:F"),0)),
NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F"&(ROW())),INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$13)&"F:F"),0))),
INDEX(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$13)&"A:A"),MATCH(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F"&(ROW())),INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$13)&"F:F"),0)),
NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F"&(ROW())),INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$14)&"F:F"),0))),
INDEX(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$14)&"A:A"),MATCH(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F"&(ROW())),INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$14)&"F:F"),0)),
NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F"&(ROW())),INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F:F"),0))),
INDEX(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"A:A"),MATCH(INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F"&(ROW())),INDIRECT((SOURCES!$B$2)&"F:F"),0))
)
```

My formulated "results" workbook also has a worksheet named "SOURCES" that I use to paste file names to connect all the data sheets corresponding columns.

Btw, I'm using this as a tool to 'un-merge' customer data between profiles in our LIVE site/database after obtaining all the tables and columns the customer key has been found (using SQL) to then compare it (using Excel) to our TEST site so I can pull apart the data that doesn't belong on the 'kept' record from the LIVE merge. In this case there were 3 records merged. Two records have a profile in the TEST site, while the kept record from the LIVE site actually does not have a TEST record, giving me 5 sheets of data to examine.

Comment: Not an answer but a note.  Avoid using INDIRECT if possible.  You are using INDIRECT in place of relative and absolute notation: `INDIRECT("A"&(ROW()))` should be `$A2` where row 2 is the first row in which the formula is placed, as it is dragged down the 2 will change to 3 and so on.  `INDIRECT("B:B")` should just be `$B:$B`.  INDIRECT is volatile and will cause the formula to recalc, even if the data does not change, whenever Excel recalcs.

Comment: I find it hard to understand what was the situation and what you were trying to achieve. Maybe a brief explanation of what information was in the original data set, and what information you are looking for specifically, and why you need to do such a match and look up?

Comment: you are probably looking for `AND()` and `OR()` (e.g., `=IF(AND(...))`

Comment: **Scott**, thank you, noted. I added more to help understand my case btw... 
**Terry**, I've added more to my op, under **ADDITION**, hope it helps... 
**Sinaraheneba**, I'll look into your suggestion and post back if needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data starting from the range A2:C2

I thing this formula can help you,
 Array Formula (Use Ctrl+Shift+Enter)

=INDEX($A2:$C2,MATCH("OK",IF(ISNUMBER($A2:$C2),"OK",""),0))